# Reset form data on tab click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I Use a jquery tabs, i have each tab with form elements like name,email phone number,
  when i enter some data into form elements and click on another tab and return on same tab, the data of the form elements is not refreshed , i want to refresh from on tab click

```
<ul class="tab">
    <li class="active" id="tab1">tab1</li>
    <li class="" id="tab2">tab2</li>
    <li class="" id="tab3">tab3</li>
    <li class="" id="tab4">tab4</li>
</ul>
<div class="tabbody" style="display: block; "></div>
<div class="tabbody" style="display: block; "></div>
<div class="tabbody" style="display: block; "></div>
<div class="tabbody" style="display: block; "></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Working Demo http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/fX7BM/

```
$('#tabs').tabs({
    beforeActivate: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).find('form').trigger('reset');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the form data on `beforeLoad` event of jquery tabs.

**[beforeLoad( event, ui )Type: tabsbeforeload](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-beforeLoad)**

Triggered when a remote tab is about to be loaded, after the beforeActivate event. Can be canceled to prevent the tab panel from loading content; though the panel will still be activated. This event is triggered just before the Ajax request is made, so modifications can be made to ui.jqXHR and ui.ajaxSettings.

Answer (score -1):

go to this site.............................

http://www.jquery4u.com/forms/jquery-function-clear-form-data/

Comment: i know to clear form even by using this simple javascript document.getElementById("divid").reset();, i want to clear data on jquery tab click